# zf2 db table relation pattern

Tags: design-patterns, zend-framework2, zend-db

i`m creating a table relation model in zf2, and want to create it right way (without doctrine module).
I have tree tables

```
| Tables_in_zf2_a  |
+------------------+
| article          |
| article_language |
| article_text     |
+------------------+

+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field     | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                            |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id        | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment                  |
| parent_id | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                             |
| added     | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP     |
+-----------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code  | varchar(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| article_id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| language_id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| title           | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| announce        | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| text            | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| seo_title       | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| seo_keywords    | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| seo_description | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| href            | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

article_text table relates with the article table with the article_id which  is primary unique  index for the article table. and relates with the article_language table by  language_id which is primary for 
The questions is what is the best practice to create the relation with the zend framework 2 db modules?
Thanks!